# Setting alias name from a subquery in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

In my Select query I just want to to set the alias name of a column based on a sub-query (that is, a value in another table). Is this possible in SQL Server 2008?

Like:

```
SELECT tax_Amt AS (SELECT tax FROM Purchase.tblTax WHERE tax_ID=@tax_ID) 
FROM Table
```

Any way to achieve the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you *cannot* dynamically set an alias or column name in standard SQL.

You'd have to use dynamic SQL if you want: but note the alias applies to the column therefore all rows have the same alias. You can't vary the alias row by row

Personally, I'd have an extra column called "TaxType" or such because it sounds like you want to vary the name per row. I'd do that anyway even if all rows have the same alias so my client code expects "TaxType"

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT tax FROM Purchase.tblTax WHERE tax_ID=@tax_ID) AS tax_Amt  
FROM Table
```

Comment: I dont want aliasing a subquery, aliasing a value with subquery returned name.

Comment: @Nithesh - I think you need to edit your question - you've not made yourself clear yet, since this answer is exactly what I was thinking you were asking for. Maybe add an example of input tables, expected results, etc?

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @From   int
DECLARE @To     int
CREATE TABLE #Rows
(
RowID     int not null primary key identity(1,1)
, SeqID int
, ColumnName varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO #Rows
SELECT DISTINCT SeqID, replace(OTE.Column1, ' ', '_') from OutputTemplateElements OTE Where TemplateID = @TemplateID Order by SeqID

SELECT @From=0, @To=@@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @From<@To
BEGIN
SET @From=@From+1

```
Set @ColumnName = (Select ColumnName from #Rows Where RowID = @From)

set @ColumnCheck = (Select count(*)
                        from sys.all_columns C
                        Join sys.all_objects O on C.object_id = O.object_id
                        where O.name like 'ConsumerWorkbenchDetails%'
                            and charindex(@ColumnName, C.name) > 0)
If @ColumnCheck = 0
    Begin
        set @sqlString = N'Alter Table ConsumerWorkbenchDetails Add ' + @ColumnName + ' nvarchar(512) NULL '
        exec sp_executesql @sqlString
    End
```

END

drop table #Rows